# if null return blank in spring data jpa Query

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa

I have the below `@Query` in my repository

```
@Query("select new Foo(id, code, coalesce(properties, '') as properties, env) "
            + "from Foo order by id desc")
    public List<Foo> findAll();
```

I want to return blank for `properties` when its `null`.
But when I run the service I am getting below error:

```
unexpected token: as near line 1, column 87
```

Any idea on how to resolve this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is "blank"? The error is coming from trying to declaring an alias in a constructor expression. Remove the `as properties`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from trying to declaring an alias in a constructor expression. Remove the `as properties`.